# what type in SQL Server to use as a writeable timestamp?

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have a table in SQL Server, tblMain.  There's a trigger that when a row changes, it basically does a SELECT * from tblMain and inserts the changed row into tblHistory.  tblHistory is a duplicate of tblMain (only much taller) and it has one extra field for a unique id.  I recently added a field of type TimeStamp (which I now understand is being deprecated, but I'll deal with that later) in order to avoid a Write Conflict problem in Microsoft Access 2007.

Obviously the trigger copies every field in tblMain to tblHistory.  It's doing a Select *.  However, if I put a field of type timeStamp in the history table to receive the field from tblMain, the trigger will fail, obviously.  What type should I use in the history table to accept a TimeStamp source?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the docs:

> A nonnullable timestamp column is semantically equivalent to a binary(8) column. A nullable timestamp column is semantically equivalent to a varbinary(8) column.

This works:

```
-- //Main table, with TIMESTAMP column
CREATE TABLE Main ( id INT, TIMESTAMP )

-- //Some values
INSERT Main VALUES ( 8, DEFAULT )
INSERT Main VALUES ( 4, DEFAULT )
INSERT Main VALUES ( 2, DEFAULT )
INSERT Main VALUES ( 7, DEFAULT )
INSERT Main VALUES ( 0, DEFAULT )

-- //See the values
SELECT * FROM Main

-- //History table
-- //with VARBINARY(8) to store a nullable TIMESTAMP
CREATE TABLE History (id INT, ts VARBINARY(8))

-- //Populate History table
INSERT History
SELECT * FROM Main

-- //See the values
SELECT * FROM History
```

Comment: A very nice answer indeed.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The `TIMESTAMP` column type is being renamed, basically, with SQL Server 2008 and up, it will be called `ROWVERSION` instead - it's not going away, just got a new name.

Now, the TIMESTAMP columns are indeed non-writable - so basically, in your trigger, you need to do an INSERT statement which lists all columns that you want to write - and omit the TIMESTAMP.

The TIMESTAMP/ROWVERSION is your best bet - only that type of column is guaranteed to be always unique, always ever-increasing for each subsequent insert. Any of the DATE-related columns could have duplicates (in SQL Server 2005, the DATETIME has an accuracy of 3.33ms - so you can definitely have duplicates).

You might want to have a combination of a TIMESTAMP for accuracy and uniqueness, and a DATETIME for human readability. The TIMESTAMP is handled by SQL Server automatically, for the `LastModifiedDate DATETIME` you could define a `DEFAULT CONSTRAINT` of `GETDATE()` so that for each insert, the current date/time would be recordded.

Comment: Thanks for the info on how to handle this going forward.

Answer (score 0):

in a trigger you can do this, which will only insert the affected rows, and is much faster than parsing the original table to find what has changed.

```
INSERT INTO tblHistory
        (col1, col2, ...)
    SELECT
        col1, col2, ...
        FROM INSERTED
```

Comment: I didn't want to have to put the column names in the trigger, because they change from time to time and it would be more of a maintenance problem.

Comment: how can you handle changing columns from the table with the history table?  Also, I hope you use the INSERTED table in the trigger.